# Is a switch statement faster than a for loop?

Tags: c, performance, for-loop, optimization, switch-statement

I am looking at the source code of the sparse bundle adjustment library [(sba)](http://users.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/sba/index.html) by Lourakis & Argyros. More precisely I am looking at the following function `nrmL2xmy` which computes the squared L2 difference of two vectors. The following code is copied from the file `sba_levmar.c` starting from line `146`:

```
/* Compute e=x-y for two n-vectors x and y and return the squared L2 norm of e.
 * e can coincide with either x or y. 
 * Uses loop unrolling and blocking to reduce bookkeeping overhead & pipeline
 * stalls and increase instruction-level parallelism; see http://www.abarnett.demon.co.uk/tutorial.html
 */
static double nrmL2xmy(double *const e, const double *const x, const double *const y, const int n)
{
const int blocksize=8, bpwr=3; /* 8=2^3 */
register int i;
int j1, j2, j3, j4, j5, j6, j7;
int blockn;
register double sum0=0.0, sum1=0.0, sum2=0.0, sum3=0.0;

  /* n may not be divisible by blocksize, 
   * go as near as we can first, then tidy up.
   */
  blockn = (n>>bpwr)<<bpwr; /* (n / blocksize) * blocksize; */

  /* unroll the loop in blocks of `blocksize'; looping downwards gains some more speed */
  for(i=blockn-1; i>0; i-=blocksize){
            e[i ]=x[i ]-y[i ]; sum0+=e[i ]*e[i ];
    j1=i-1; e[j1]=x[j1]-y[j1]; sum1+=e[j1]*e[j1];
    j2=i-2; e[j2]=x[j2]-y[j2]; sum2+=e[j2]*e[j2];
    j3=i-3; e[j3]=x[j3]-y[j3]; sum3+=e[j3]*e[j3];
    j4=i-4; e[j4]=x[j4]-y[j4]; sum0+=e[j4]*e[j4];
    j5=i-5; e[j5]=x[j5]-y[j5]; sum1+=e[j5]*e[j5];
    j6=i-6; e[j6]=x[j6]-y[j6]; sum2+=e[j6]*e[j6];
    j7=i-7; e[j7]=x[j7]-y[j7]; sum3+=e[j7]*e[j7];
  }

  /*
   * There may be some left to do.
   * This could be done as a simple for() loop, 
   * but a switch is faster (and more interesting) 
   */

  i=blockn;
  if(i<n){ 
  /* Jump into the case at the place that will allow
   * us to finish off the appropriate number of items. 
   */
    switch(n - i){ 
      case 7 : e[i]=x[i]-y[i]; sum0+=e[i]*e[i]; ++i;
      case 6 : e[i]=x[i]-y[i]; sum0+=e[i]*e[i]; ++i;
      case 5 : e[i]=x[i]-y[i]; sum0+=e[i]*e[i]; ++i;
      case 4 : e[i]=x[i]-y[i]; sum0+=e[i]*e[i]; ++i;
      case 3 : e[i]=x[i]-y[i]; sum0+=e[i]*e[i]; ++i;
      case 2 : e[i]=x[i]-y[i]; sum0+=e[i]*e[i]; ++i;
      case 1 : e[i]=x[i]-y[i]; sum0+=e[i]*e[i]; ++i;
    }
  }

  return sum0+sum1+sum2+sum3;
}
```

In the middle of the code (roughly), the authors state the following:

```
 /*
   * There may be some left to do.
   * This could be done as a simple for() loop, 
   * but a switch is faster (and more interesting) 
   */
```

I don't understand why a `switch` is faster than a simple `for` loop.

So my question is: **Is this statement true?** and if so, **why**?

Comment: I did not get your point. `for` is a loop and `switch` is a single _decision_ at best. How you can compare them?

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Look at the cases, and you will see that they do not end with `break` and therefore will fall through. It's simply a kind of [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling).

Comment: *Is this statement true?*  Only one way to find out ...

Comment: By the way, IMO while this may be more optimal (especially if the function is called often) it could be a case of premature optimization (the compiler might be able to unroll), and also a way of the programmer(s) to show off some cleverness, and as most optimization and cleverness in programming, it obfuscates the code and makes it harder to understand and maintain.

Comment: it should be noted the 'register' modifier , in modern C compilers, has only one effect.  Specifically cannot get the address of the variable.  I.E. you can remove the 'register' modifiers.

Comment: placing more than one statement on a line in the source file has only one effect.  Specifically the code is harder to read.

Comment: there is the #pragma for unrolling loops.   There is no effective (due to the extra math being performed) speed increase with the posted 'method' of unrolling a loop.   (optimization for speed during the compile step and linking 'static' will have a much larger effect on the execution speed.

Answer (score 6):

A switch is faster in that situation, because a loop would check the end condition several times, whereas a switch does it only once. This is called [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling), and optimising compilers largely do it on their own.

Answer (score 5):

The switch case in question uses fall-through in all of its cases, so it is basically an unrolled `for` loop.  This would most likely be (slightly) faster because there is no comparison operation being performed.

Given the small number of cases, any performance difference would be negligible, so from a code readability standpoint a `for` loop would be better.

Answer (score 0):

example: Can only generate output if the value matches. When the age is 18 or when the age is 60 . No comarison of data based on greater than or smaller than. Compares data based on equality.

For Loop : Checks the value of data is less than or greater than. (in ranges).
example: can tell weather an input age is more than 18 and less than 60.

Switch Case: Checks the value of data that is prespecified. only equal to.

From what you have said I would go with a for loop.